# Creating a word file in PHP and attaching it to a mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

**The way I create my Word document is this :**

```
  // I use my templace that's with my files : 
    $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('Template.docx');

// I fill the template values from an sql query : 
    $templateProcessor->setValue('titre', $options['titre']);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('source', $options['source']);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('auteur', $options['auteur']);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('date_pub', $options['date_pub']);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('contenu', $options['contenu']);

 // I give the user the file (I don't fully understand how this works but it does)

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$title.docx");
    $templateProcessor->saveAs('php://output');
```

**The way people recommend attaching files to php mails is the following:**

```
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->SetFrom('you@example.com', 'Your Name'); //Name is optional
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

I have a problem with the **PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_Here** part, The code I use for creating the word document just serves it to the user so they download it, but what is the path to it ?

Help is really appreciated, thanks

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones When I used the '$templateProcessor->saveAs('NewWordFile.docx');' I would find the file with the source code files, are u suggesting I access that and send it and then delete it ?

Comment: Okay sir thank you, Any advise on how to delete that file using php code ?

Comment: Thank u man , How do I choose ur answer as the correct one ?

Comment: I compiled my comments into an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the file on your server first in order to attach it to an email. You can [delete the file from your server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) after sending the email.

The `header()` and `php://output` are telling the user's browser to download the file, so if you remove the header and change `saveAs()` to be a real (writeable) path on your server, you should end up with a file that you can then attach to an email.

I'd recommend writing the file to a new location (above your server root) to store these temporary files rather than within the source code. Then `->saveAs('/path/to/file/File.docx');` and `$file_to_attach = '/path/to/file/File.docx';`.

Comment: You don’t need to save it to a file. You can keep it in memory (in a variable) and serve it to the browser, and then attach the same thing to an email using `addStringAttachment()`.

Comment: I'm not sure how generating a file via `TemplateProcessor` works as a variable (https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates-processing.html). Are you saying they can leave `->saveAs('php://output')` and just remove the `header()`, and change the email to use `addStringAttachment()` instead of `AddAttachment()`?

Comment: Though it's not clear how their "create a Word doc" code and their "send an email" code are related. If this is an option, they may need to do some further tinkering with return values to get this working.